# How can I turn this list of values into a stacked (and combined?) bar chart where every value is shown per day?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, bar-chart

I have a list of values with an amount and a date.

I would like to display it like a stacked (?) bar chart where each value is marked with its own box, and then displayed on the corresponding day – adding up to the total for each day.

I understand there might be a few manipulations needed of the table, but am not good enough in Excel programming to figure out how to do this. The example table is small enough to allow manual sorting, but ideally I'm looking for a solution that also work with large tables.

[image: See image of what I have and what I want]

Here is a different answer that is very similar:
[Create a stacked bar chart that displays data in monthly intervals?](https://superuser.com/questions/790026/create-a-stacked-bar-chart-that-displays-data-in-monthly-intervals?rq=1)

but that example uses months instead, and I can't seem to crack how to get it to work with days in my table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your data by Date.

Add a new column called ID with this formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,1,C1+1)
```

[image]

Drag the formula to the bottom of the list.

Now create a pivot chart using Insert>Pivot Chart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That worked very well, although I had to type in the formula manually for it to work (small tip to any other Mac Office-users. )

Comment: Actually: I had to write the formula like this (with semikolons instead of commas): `=IF(A3<>A2;1;C2+1)`

Comment: The commas vs semicolons are a regional difference in characters used for array element separators. Do you also use different decimal and thousands separators?

Comment: @FlexYourData - clever.